# Display Suite Fields not showing

Tags: 8, display-suite

I created a bootstrap sub theme and and have enabled display suite.  I have enabled ds extra fields and chose a layout for my content type for full view display.  When going to the full view page of my content none of the ds fields are showing.

I have enabled title, author, post date, submitted by but none of these are showing.  Is there something special you must do to get ds to work on a subtheme?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Drupal are you using? If 8.3 you may wanna update to DS 8.x-3.0-beta3 which no longer requires the layout plugin module, instead uses "Layout Discovery" in core.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2871283